# Upload Files to Mainframes from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ftp, mainframe

I am trying to upload a file from my pc to mainframes. I am trying to upload it using Chilkat FTP2. Below is the code.

The file I am trying to upload is 2009102600000

```
Dim ftp As New Chilkat.Ftp2()

Dim success As Boolean

' Any string unlocks the component for the 1st 30-days.'
success = ftp.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial")
If (success <> true) Then
    MsgBox(ftp.LastErrorText)
    Exit Sub
End If


ftp.Hostname = "www.myside.com"
ftp.Username = "****"
ftp.Password = "****"

' The default data transfer mode is "Active" as opposed to "Passive".'
' Change it to Passive by setting the Passive property:'
ftp.Passive = true

' Connect and login to the FTP server.'
success = ftp.Connect()
If (success <> true) Then
    MsgBox(ftp.LastErrorText)
    Exit Sub
End If


' Change to the remote directory where the file will be uploaded.'
success = ftp.ChangeRemoteDir("ABC.SITEUPLOAD.UPLOAD")
If (success <> true) Then
    MsgBox(ftp.LastErrorText)
    Exit Sub
End If


' Upload a file.'
Dim localFilename As String
localFilename = "c:\2009102600000"
Dim remoteFilename As String
remoteFilename = "2009102600000"

success = ftp.PutFile(localFilename,remoteFilename)
If (success <> true) Then
    MsgBox(ftp.LastErrorText)
    Exit Sub
End If


ftp.Disconnect()

MsgBox("File Uploaded!")
```

The error I am getting is dataset not found use MVS dsn name or something like that.

I would really appreciate if you can help me out with this one please.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not at all sure you can treat data set prefixes as directories. When I'm doing uploads to the mainframe with ftp, I always just specify the full target name. I would get rid of the

```
ftp.ChangeRemoteDir("ABC.SITEUPLOAD.UPLOAD")
```

section altogether and just change:

```
remoteFilename = "2009102600000"
```

to:

```
remoteFilename = "'ABC.SITEUPLOAD.UPLOAD.2009102600000'"
```

if it's a sequesntial data set, or:

```
remoteFilename = "'ABC.SITEUPLOAD.UPLOAD(2009102600000)'"
```

if it's a member (in which case the data set will have to exist first).

It would also help if you changed the `MsgBox` statements so that they included an indication as to *what* is actually causing the error. Something along the lines of:

```
MsgBox("Connect error: " & ftp.LastErrorText)
MsgBox("ChangeRemoteDir error: " & ftp.LastErrorText)
MsgBox("PutFile error: " & ftp.LastErrorText)
```

instead of the generic:

```
MsgBox(ftp.LastErrorText)
```

*One other point:* you'll notice I've put single quotes around the targets above. That's because z/OS has a habit of (sometimes) prefixing your login name to members. It may be that:

```
put xyz.txt upload(xyz)
```

is actually trying to put it into `yourname.upload(xyz)`. Quoting it will prevent that.

*Update:* You know, I just noticed something that totally escaped me the first time I read this question. The error message spells it out plainly.

Data set name segments and member names within partitioned data sets are limited to 8 characters. Hence your `'ABC.SITEUPLOAD.UPLOAD(2009102600000)'` is invalid on *two* counts, the `SITEUPLOAD` and the `2009102600000`. Try shortening the names and re-transferring.

Here's the proof:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Pax> ftp bigiron
Connected to bigiron.box.com.
220-FTPD1 IBM FTP CS V1R9 at BIGIRON.BOX.COM, 02:15:23 on 2009-11-06.
220 Connection will close if idle for more than 5 minutes.
User (bigiron.box.com:(none)): pax
331 Send password please.
Password:
230 PAX is logged on.  Working directory is "PAX.".

ftp> put test.txt 'pax.siteupload'
200 Port request OK.
501 Invalid data set name "'pax.siteupload'".  Use MVS Dsname conventions.

ftp> put test.txt 'pax.siteupld'
200 Port request OK.
125 Storing data set PAX.SITEUPLD
250 Transfer completed successfully.
ftp: 177 bytes sent in 0.00Seconds 177000.00Kbytes/sec.

ftp> put test.txt 'pax.jcl(abcdefghi)'
200 Port request OK.
501 Invalid data set name "'pax.jcl(abcdefghi)'".  Use MVS Dsname conventions.

ftp> put test.txt 'pax.jcl(abcdefgh)'
200 Port request OK.
125 Storing data set PAX.JCL(ABCDEFGH)
250 Transfer completed successfully.
ftp: 177 bytes sent in 0.00Seconds 177000.00Kbytes/sec.

ftp> bye
221 Quit command received. Goodbye.
```

Comment: Paxdiablo,
Thanks for your kind response. But I tried all the options you mentioned But I still get the same error. I am able to download the file but not upload. Please helo

Comment: @acadia, a few questions (1) is it a sequentail dataset or a member of a PDS(E)? (2) can your log onto the box and use ISPF to get information on that member - use option 3.4 DSLIST with the 'i' line command? (3) When logged onto ISPF can you edit that member (maybe there's a RACF issue)? (4) Which error did you get, connect, chdir or put?

Comment: (5) Show the *exact* error message you're getting. If I can't help you with that information, you'll probably need to turn to your sysprogs - they will be able to determine what you're doing from the system logs on the big iron.

Comment: Paxdiablo, Sorry for the delay in responding. I am still not able to fix the issue. Below is the error I am getting STOR failed Filename: 'ABC.SITEUPLOAD.UPLOAD(1250178379029)' FtpResponse24: 501 Invalid data set name "'ABC.SITEUPLOAD.UPLOAD(1250178379029)'". Use MVS Dsname conventions. Failed.

Comment: I know this question is old, but I just stumbled upon it. The member name 1250178379029 is not valid because under MVS names must begin with a alphabetic character and must not be longer than 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't need to store it as a generational dataset from the root directory?  Like this:

```
'ABC.SITEUPLOAD.UPLOAD.2009102600000(+1)'
```